# I want to map rows from Sheet one on and excel file to other sheets if they meet certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work in sales and cover a large territory.  To manage the territory, I break it up into "Zones" (i.e. Philly / Pittsburgh / etc).  My organization provides an excel file with every company I call on and a litany of sales information - this is Sheet 1 of my excel workbook.  I've already inserted an extra column on Sheet 1 and labeled "Zone" to identify where each company will fall into.

To simplify the management within each zone, I want separate Sheets for each of the named zones.  What I'd like to know is what formula I can enter on the sheet labeled "Philly" such that "if" the Zone Column on Sheet 1 = "Philly", then the entire row will map to the sheet labeled Philly.

Further, some zones have sub-zones (i.e Central PA) and so I'd like one sheet to search for any Sheet 1 Zone equal to Harrisburg, State College, Scranton, etc and bring them all to the one sheet named Central PA in the same fashion as above.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here at SuperUser, we usually include what we've tried in the questions. I think what you're looking for is VLOOKUP, have you tried that yet? A quick search could set you right up.

Comment: @Wutnaut is right as far as a function. IMO, that will take a lot of formula typing. You may want to consider [pivot tables](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/) as well. Or [Power Query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/microsoft-power-query-for-excel-help-HA104003813.aspx) maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the Sheet1 range to an Excel Table (from the Insert Ribbon).  Then you can use the Filter buttons on the column heading cells to select e.g. Zone = Philly, which will then only show you the Philly rows.

This approach is very simple to maintain and avoids formulas and duplicating data.  A consolidated table is also a great source for charts, Pivot Tables, Power View etc.